# How to view Pending LinkedIn Connections message?

Tags: linkedin, linkedin-messages

When people send me a LinkedIn invitation to connect, I used to be able to view the message they sent.  It seems to have disappeared recently, how do I see the message before I accept or ignore their connection request?

Comment: It's a shame they removed it

Comment: I spent 2 hours searching answer for this, but couldn't find. This is indeed shameful.